# How to output my function into my html when button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

FYI I am new to coding, I have looked up online everywhere to do this but can't seem to figure it out. I feel like I am doing the right thing but nothing is being displayed in my html code when I press my submit button. [HTML & Javascript Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGtFW.jpg)

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), in particular the bit about **not** posting pictures of text.

Comment: Your function is *returning* text, so line 15 is never reached; JS exits the function beforehand. Plus you're setting output's text to `b` which is the value entered by the user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because in your if statements you return if true. This will return the text from the function.

```js
var text = '';

if (b == a) {
  text = "your text";
}

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave a comment but it seems you are not linking the js file. in your html you have:

```
<script text=".." src="index.js"></script>
```

it should be

```
<script text=".." src="./MoneySaved/index.js"></script>
```

second thing, you have return statements before you change the innerHTML of your HTMLElement, so you never reach the code in line 15.